# How to reproduce cookie SQL injection locally?

Tags: sql, security, cookies, xampp, sql-injection

I have a website that is vulnerable to SQL injection through cookies. I have these cookies: `user, pwd`.
If I set the value of user to `randomnameuser'#` I can skip the authentication control.

To test the site i'm trying to run the same site locally using XAMPP, the problem is that locally is not possible to attack the cookies with SQL injection using the same string used in the site i have online.

I have'nt changed anything, how is it possible?

Comment: So is your actual question: How to reproduce the exploitation of the vulnerability locally?

Comment: Yes, this is the point.

Comment: It's most silly part called magic quotes. Yet a good application have to be written such a way to be safe with *any* settings. *That is* indeed the point.

Comment: Thanks, was a problem of magic quotes. I haven't check before because magic quotes are removed from 5.4 but I forgot that I was using an older version of php to assure compatibility with scripts.

Problem solved.

Comment: Unfortunately, problem is not solved even a little

Comment: Yes, now the magic quotes are disabled like in the website and the site is exploitable also in local.

I have already solved the problem on the website online but i wanted the local exploitable only to see some "things".

Comment: Means you had no injection protection for your site at all. Quod erat demonstrandum

Comment: NO. I have read many times that is not good use magic quotes.

I use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: What magic quotes has to do here? The **fact** is: you just deployed a site with vulnerable code. Means your code had no protection from injection. `"I have a website that is vulnerable to SQL"` are your own words, mind you

Comment: And I have reasons to conclude that it is still vulnerable.

Comment: "The fact is: you just deployed a site with vulnerable code. Means your code had no protection from injection."



The fact is: you don't understand the question. The point wasn't the vulnerability on my website but " How to reproduce the exploitation of the vulnerability locally"

Comment: It's all right. Right now I am talking not of the question but of the site. Which is still vulnerable, no matter if I understood your question or not.

Comment: 1. You are NOT using  mysql_real_escape_string, for if you really were using it, you would asked no questions. 2. This function has nothjng to do with injections at all. Your comforting friends did you a disservice. As it often happens with comforting friends, you know.

Comment: 1. I used it after discovering the sql injection problem. "if you really were using it, you would asked no questions." The question wasn't how to resolve the sql injection problem. 
2. "This function has nothjng to do with injections at all." It's true. Comforting friends? I don't know what are you talking about.

Problem solved.

Comment: 1. For some reason you cannot follow the conversation. Some of my comments refers not the question but mere responses to your comments. 2. Using mysql_real_escape_string does not solve any problem. 3. In your place, studying PHP for only month, I wouldn't be so self-confident (to the point of arrogance), yet I wouldn't be so sure in the solutions. Just a friendly warning.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing password in a cookie. See [this post](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/) for a good persistent login cookie system (I assume that's what you are doing).

Answer (score 0):

It means your local environment setup differs from the server one. If you compare the resulting queries you should see the difference.

Should be a simple escaping issue - just sanitize your values before using them in query.

Comment: "Just sanitize" is not an answer. Nobody in the whole world actually knows what this "sanitize" means.

Comment: hm, nobody but google then :) "san·i·tize - make clean and hygienic"

Comment: Well, I eager to see how you going to wash your data with soap :)

Comment: @bcat That’s rather a medical definition of sanitize. However, technical [definitions of sanitization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanitization) range from “anonymization” to “redaction”, and none of them describe adequately what should happen in this case.

Comment: @Your Common Sense The answer had to do with the question "how is it possible?" - server setup difference. The way-too-general word "sanitize" was used because the question itself is pretty general. So your downvote doesn't seem right to me (but again I might be biased here)

Comment: Still vague "server settings" is the same "useful" answer as "sanitize your input". It actually answers nothing. I'd upvote your answer if you, even knowing no real answer, told the OP how to *debug* his code, how can he discover the problem himself.

Comment: @Your Common Sense An answer to the question, even if it's "still vague", is better then a big side note without reading the actual question. I guess I have to live with this world being unjust then :)

Comment: it's weak excuse, you know

Answer (score -3):

Even without reading the question body

## There is no such thing like "SQL injection on cookies"!

**Data source has absolutely nothing to do with injections**

It's **destination** that matters: all you need is always format your queries properly.

## For a properly formatted query, no injection ever possible

no matter if data source is a cookie, or JSON request, or whatever.

Knowing that, it's easy to answer the question " how is it possible?": **you don't format your queries properly.** You should use **prepared statements** for running your queries, which makes them guaranteed safe (though for the most regular and simple cases only).

On a side note, storing password in a cookie in a plaint ext is also extremely insecure. You have to store a strong salted hash instead.

Comment: This does not answer his question of how he can reproduce it on his local machine.

Comment: SQL INJECTION USING COOKIES AS DATA SOURCE is better? It's for my bad english, i know how sql injection works.

I'm not looking how to sanitize input, but how can i reproduce the same exploitation locally. Because i don't understand why the exploitation doesn't work locally without i have changed anything

Comment: @Gumbo You SO folks are too direct in your answers. His real problem is vulnerable code through lack of prepared statements. Have this solved, this silly magic quotes issue wouldn't have much importance anymore.

Comment: @NxA Please read my answer trough, not only emphasized line. Data source **never matters**. See?

Comment: @YourCommonSense His question did not give any hint that he was looking for a solution to his actual, major problem, the SQL Injection vulnerability. It just states that he doesn’t know why it doesn’t work locally: “I have'nt changed anything, how is it possible?” Maybe he already knows the solution to the SQL Injection problem (hopefully) and just wanted to see what exactly happens behind the curtains. I rather think that it’s you that likes to jump on the train of giving sermons with bold letters.

Comment: @NxA sorry, but you just have said nonsense: if you *really* knew "how sql injection works" and how to "sanitize" "input" (both quoted words have no precise meaning by the way) - this question would never appeared here.

Comment: @Gumbo it's your speculations only. But in fact we can see a question titled "SQL injection through cookie" which clearly states that the OP knows NO "solution to the SQL Injection already".

Comment: @YourCommonSense Well, and that’s your speculations.

Comment: @Gumbo How's that? So, you agree that "SQL injections through cookies" have to be handled some special way, different from injection through, say, query string?!

Comment: @YourCommonSense No, definitely not. Your answer is correct in substance. But your whole answer was obviously biased just by reading the title and “even without reading the question body”. And that’s the problem here as your answer is kind of off-topic regarding his actual question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Well i'm not saying that sql injections through cookies have to be handled some special way,   I specified the data source because I thought there was any configuration that could cause problems with the cookies.

I wanted know only How to reproduce the exploitation of the vulnerability locally and i have already a solution for this sql injection.

But now, as I wrote, the problem is solved.

Comment: @Gumbo the question body bears the same insane statement, mind you. I know, the *actual* purpose of SO is to comfort developers, to devise excuses for them. Well, I am not fit for this business. And surely my answer for the root problem will be much more useful for the *declared* purpose. Adios.